# Ansible - Can't access value - Got error: 'dict object' has no attribute

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    var_folder_path: /home/play
  tasks:
    - name: Include all yaml files in directories
      include_vars:
        dir: "{{ var_folder_path }}/vars"
        extensions:
          - 'yaml'

    - name: "Print Variable Name"
      shell: echo "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - "{{ global.globalname.property.Name }}"
        - "{{ S3.secret }}"
```

My var files under /home/play/vars

**example_1.yaml**

```
global:
  globalname:
    property:
      cipher: DEFAULT
      client:
        type: dynamic
      Name: test-run
```

**example_2.yaml**

```
gcp:
  keyname: sample-run
S3:
  secret: run
Resources: false
celery:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 5
```

When I execute the playbook I get the below error. Not sure why the values are not loading

`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'globalname'"}`

Comment: The above playbook works fine for me. The only error I see is with the S3 dictionary in example_2.yaml, which should be s3 (lower case). Do you have more yaml files inside  /home/play/vars ? If yes, is "global" var defined in more than one file ?

Comment: Why is a loop needed?

Comment: for some reason the dot-notation for accessing members of dictionaries never worked for me either. try `global['globalname']`

Answer (score 2):

To debug a playbook when an error occurs, it is very often a good idea to insert a `debug` task.

In your case insert a `debug` task before the `shell` task and get the whole variable `global` output:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: global
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment above, there are no issues with the playbooks you shared, except for the "S3" variable definition in example_2.yaml, which should be "s3" (in lower case).

One possible cause for the error you reported is that there are more than one "global" var definition in the var files at /home/play/vars, and is overriding the global var definition in example_1.yaml.
Default Ansible merge is in ASCII order, i.e., the last group loaded overwrites the previous groups. See [how-variables-are-merged](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-variables-are-merged) from Ansible official documentation for more details on how variables are merged in Ansible and update your var files accordingly.

As mentioned by user @phanaz in the other answer, its a good practice to use "debug" module for printing the vars to validate, in such scenarios.

Comment: I don't have any other files in `/home/play/vars`. Anyhow, I approached the problem in a different way, Thanks for the suggestions!